# SAM CLI breaks at /var/runtime/index.js every time I invoke my function

Tags: node.js, docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, aws-sam-cli

I created the configurations to be able to invoke my lambda function directly using sam CLI. The configuration copy is shown below (using code lens).

[image: function invoking example]

When I click F5 or press the run button to debug my function it breaks every time in a file that is not in my project called index.js created in the runtime (/var/runtime/index.js) (I believe it's related to sam CLI debugging feature).

This stalls my development process as I expect it breaks directly at the breakpoint I put in the code.

Steps to reproduce:
1- Run sam init
2- Choose option 1 (1 - AWS Quick Start Templates)
3- Choose option 2 (2 - Image (artifact is an image uploaded to an ECR image repository)
4- Choose option 1 (1- amazon/nodejs14.x-base)
5- Go to app.js file then click on the code lens option (add debug configuration)

[image: Codelens add debug configuration]

6- Go to run and debug tab in VS code then select the function configuration you just created and then click the run button

[image: invoke sam function]

Observed result:
It breaks at a breakpoint that does not exist

[image: unexpected behavior]

Expected result:
To break at the breakpoint that I put by myself in the code

Additional environment details (Ex: Windows, Mac, Amazon Linux, etc)
OS: macOS Big Sur version: 11.5.1
sam --version: SAM CLI, version 1.31.0
AWS region: US East